# Ubuntu Server en Virtual Box

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, ubuntu-server

Tengo una instalación de Ubuntu Server 18.04 en Virtual Box y presento las siguientes dificultades.

1) Necesito poder moverme hacia arriba en la consola. Cuando ejecuto un comando y me muestra una serie de logs, solo puedo ver los ultimos que caben dentro de la pantalla y me es imposible hacer ningun tipo de scroll para observar los logs mas arriba.

2) Por otro lado me gustaria agrandar el tamaño de la pantalla de la maquina virtual, pues esta se ve muy pequeña.

Gracias por su colaboracion.

Comment: Puede configurar el acceso a la máquina virtual a través de ssh. Esto es más conveniente que trabajar a través de una ventana de máquina virtual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Para moverte hacia arriba y abajo por la consola utiliza SHIFT + RePag/AvPag.
No se si tendrás problemas al tener captura de teclado activa o no en virtual box.

2) En la barra de herramientas superior tienes la opcion VER, en la que puedes elegir el tipo de pantalla, completa, ventana , etc y redimensionar o cambiar resolución

PD: Si no puedes moverte por la consola prueba a utilizar la opción de Virtual Box de capturar teclado. Suele estar en la barra inferior parte derecha.

Espero que solucione tus problemas.

Comment: No encuentro las teclas RePag y AvPag en mi teclado. Las que veo son pgup y pgdn y no me funcionan

Comment: Mantienes pulsado SHIFT? Si PgUp y PgDn son las mismas. Si no te funciona clicka en la terminal para poner el foco, si sigue sin funcionar , selecciona la opcion capturar atajos de teclado en la barra inferior de VB

Comment: Perdón la opción capturar teclado. Creo que con la rueda del raton tmb puedes navegar por la terminal